# Deleting columns from a dataframe in R based on number of values >0

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some columns contain very few values above 0, and I would like to delete those columns.

For example, if I would like to delete all columns with less than 5 values above 0 in the following data.frame, how would I go about that?

```
Name,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
Row1,0,0,0,0,10,400
Row2,125.0,2.50,0,0,5,0
Row3,10,0,0,10,100,70
Row4,10,0,50,0,0,10
Row5,489,0,30,0,35,50
Row6,0,0,450.5,0,10,400
Row7,125.5,0,2.50,0,0,5
Row8,10,0,0.50,10,100,70
Row9,10,0,50,0,0,10
Row10,489,0,0,0,35,50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to combine `colSums` with logical subsetting:

```
df1[, colSums(df1 > 0) >= 5]
#       Col1  Col3 Col5 Col6
#Row1    0.0   0.0   10  400
#Row2  125.0   0.0    5    0
#Row3   10.0   0.0  100   70
#Row4   10.0  50.0    0   10
#Row5  489.0  30.0   35   50
#Row6    0.0 450.5   10  400
#Row7  125.5   2.5    0    5
#Row8   10.0   0.5  100   70
#Row9   10.0  50.0    0   10
#Row10 489.0   0.0   35   50
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0, 125, 10, 10, 489, 0, 125.5, 10, 10, 
       489), Col2 = c(0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Col3 = c(0, 0, 
        0, 50, 30, 450.5, 2.5, 0.5, 50, 0), Col4 = c(0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L), Col5 = c(10L, 5L, 100L, 0L, 35L, 10L, 
        0L, 100L, 0L, 35L), Col6 = c(400L, 0L, 70L, 10L, 50L, 400L, 5L, 
       70L, 10L, 50L)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", 
       "Col6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Row1", "Row2", 
       "Row3", "Row4", "Row5", "Row6", "Row7", "Row8", "Row9", "Row10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `Filter` (Using data from @RHertel's post)

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x>0)>=5, df1)
#       Col1  Col3 Col5 Col6
#Row1    0.0   0.0   10  400
#Row2  125.0   0.0    5    0
#Row3   10.0   0.0  100   70
#Row4   10.0  50.0    0   10
#Row5  489.0  30.0   35   50
#Row6    0.0 450.5   10  400
#Row7  125.5   2.5    0    5
#Row8   10.0   0.5  100   70
#Row9   10.0  50.0    0   10
#Row10 489.0   0.0   35   50
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help do what you want. This counts the number observations in a column.

```
library(plyr)

count(dataframe, names(dataframe))
```

Using what the other guy's answer was for the df1 was.

```
count(df1, "Col1")

   Col1 freq
1   0.0    2
2  10.0    4
3 125.0    1
4 125.5    1
5 489.0    2
```

To loop through columns, use some apply function or for loop to get what you want.

From here, you just need to do an "if" statement to check whether that the freq <= 5 for 0, and just delete it accordingly.